# Loop over Publisher Combine framework

Tags: swift, combine

I have the following function to perform an URL request:

```swift
final class ServiceManagerImpl: ServiceManager, ObservableObject {
    private let session = URLSession.shared

    func performRequest<T>(_ request: T) -> AnyPublisher<String?, APIError> where T : Request {
        session.dataTaskPublisher(for: self.urlRequest(request))
            .tryMap { data, response in
                try self.validateResponse(response)
                return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            }
            .mapError { error in
                return self.transformError(error)
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Having these 2 following functions, I can now call the desired requests from corresponded *ViewModel*:

```swift
final class AuditServiceImpl: AuditService {
    private let serviceManager: ServiceManager = ServiceManagerImpl()

    func emptyAction() -> AnyPublisher<String?, APIError> {
        let request = AuditRequest(act: "", nonce: String.randomNumberGenerator)
        return serviceManager.performRequest(request)
    }

    func burbleAction(offset: Int) -> AnyPublisher<String?, APIError> {
        let request = AuditRequest(act: "burble", nonce: String.randomNumberGenerator, offset: offset)
        return serviceManager.performRequest(request)
    }
}
```

```swift
final class AuditViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var auditLog: String = ""
    private let auditService: AuditService = AuditServiceImpl()

    init() {
        let timer = Timer(timeInterval: 5, repeats: true) { _ in
            self.getBurbles()
        }
        RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common)
    }

    func getBurbles() {
        auditService.emptyAction()
            .flatMap { [unowned self] offset -> AnyPublisher<String?, APIError> in
                let currentOffset = Int(offset?.unwrapped ?? "") ?? 0
                return self.auditService.burbleAction(offset: currentOffset)
            }
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { [unowned self] completion in
                print(completion)
            }, receiveValue: { [weak self] burbles in
                self?.auditLog = burbles!
            })
            .store(in: &cancellableSet)
    }
}
```

Everything is fine when I use `self.getBurbles()` for the first time. However, for the next calls, `print(completion)` shows `finished`, and the code doesn't perform `self?.auditLog = burbles!`

I don't know how can I loop over the `getBurbles()` function and get the response at different intervals.

**Edit**

The whole process in a nutshell:

- I call `getBurbles()` from class initializer
- `getBurbles()` calls 2 nested functions: `emptyAction()` and `burbleAction(offset: Int)`
- Those 2 functions generate different requests and call `performRequest<T>(_ request: T)`
- Finally, I set the response into `auditLog` variable and show it on the *SwiftUI* layer

Comment: Instead of just showing some methods, could you be very clear about what class each of those methods is in? and where and how the class is held? It seems like the problem might be that you're reusing the same publisher but it's hard to tell from here.

Comment: @matt Please check the updated version, hopefully it is clear now

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 issues here.

First when a `Publisher` errors it will never produce elements again.  That's a problem here because you want to recycle the Publisher here and call it many times, even if the inner `Publisher` fails.  You need to handle the error inside the `flatMap` and make sure it doesn't propagate to the enclosing `Publisher`. (ie you can return a `Result` or some other `enum` or tuple that indicates you should display an error state).

Second, `flatMap` is almost certainly not what you want here since it will merge all of the api calls and return them in arbitrary order.  If you want to cancel any existing requests and only show the latest results then you should use `.map` followed by [switchToLatest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3204759-switchtolatest).